# How to detect current page in WordPress plugin development

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently developing a plugin where I will restrict certain pages to the logged-in users only. I mean the normal pages we create in Wordpress.

I found this online but it does not seem to work for me.

```
function check_the_current_page(){
    echo $slug = basename(get_permalink());
}

add_action( "init", "check_the_current_page" );
```

Another option I had was to detect current page id as shown in the code below. nothing gets printed on the screen, probably I'm using the wrong hook or something, someone help me

```
function check_the_current_page(){
    global $post;
    echo "Post id: ".$post->ID;
}

add_action( "init", "check_the_current_page" );
```

if only I'm able to get output in one of the above scenarios, then it would be very simple, but now nothing is being printed on the screen for both scenarios

Comment: If you're trying to debug plugin code by output, I suggest you use `debug_log("...");` and enable the debug log in WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Try This Code Work For Me global $post dosent work in init`

```
function check_the_current_page() {
    global $post;
    echo "Post id: " . $post->ID;
}

add_action( "wp", "check_the_current_page" );
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I was getting it wrong on the hook, it has now worked